# How to validate Mongoose path before it throws a CastError?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am having trouble with this CastError behaviour using Mongoose with Nodejs.

This is my schema:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    price : {
        required : true,
        type     : Number
    }
});

var CatalogSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    items : [ItemSchema]
});

ItemSchema.path('price').validate(function(price){
    // This code will not run due to CastError
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(price));
});
```

Using the above schemas, when I try to update the schema and pass an invalid value to `price` (ie. 'ABC123'), Mongoose throws an error right away before any validation functions are ran on the `.path('price')`

Actual Response:

```
{ 
    name: 'CastError',
    type: 'number',
    value: 'ABC123',
    path: 'price'
}
```

Expected Response:

```
{
    name : 'ValidationError',
    errors : {
        'items.0.price' : {
            name: 'CastError',
            path: 'price',
            type: 'number',
            value: 'ABC123'
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve my expected response?

Comment: Oh! ya.. he was pretty unpleasant. That's good to hear.

Answer (score 0):

The schema enforces the input type, essentially providing you with a validation mechanism. So the response you're getting is mongoose telling you that ABC123 which is a string cannot be casted to 'price' which can only be a number. If you'd like to instead use your own validation, then simply remove the 'type : Number' reference in the schema.